# The notification doesn't include App Name at Notification Center only?But,Banners and Lock Screen do

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I wonder why my app name doesn't include at Notification Center when the message arrive.

Notifications that are appear at Lock Screen View and Banners include my **AppName** and **Message(title)** in the notification view.

But,why my **AppName** is not included at Notification Center like other App?
Please check this

[image: Notification Center when my notification from my app arrive.There is no my app name.But,pushover included its app name]

There is no my app name(xxxxx) as you can see[Compare with pushover].It only showing title and body of notification that I sent for server.Not the app name.

Please help,Is that a problem with my app or?Push notification service that I used for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is setting the title as [Change Bid Price] #1… which replaces the application title. If you leave the title blank, then it would be set to the application name.

Comment: I think it's not right with title.Then why the application name appear on Banner alert and Lock Screen alert when notification received.

Comment: Only notification appear at Notification Center doesn't include My App Name.But,it include title and body of notifications.

Comment: The banner and lock screen alerts will always show the application name and not your custom title. You can find this discussed in this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34029734/83491

Comment: You know we can't touch notification setting of app bundle,title and body of notification received to be appear at our phone.I mean the problem of mine is,on notification center only,the title is not showing the app name.Actually,it should be App Bundle Name,Title and body at notification center when the notification arrived.I think there is something wrong with one signal sdk or my app.Now,I am testing with local notification.If it worked out,then the problem is from OneSignal.

Comment: @jwilm ,you are right,Its because the server send the title and body like the above image for pushing notification.If I set title = (My App Name) at OneSignal new push message,it will appear like pushover.Thanks.Apologies,for my mistake.